# Cassandra Add Node Streaming Timeout

Tags: cassandra, timeout, streaming

Unable to add a new node to a Cassandra 1.2 ring because streaming times out. We have streaming_socket_timeout_in_ms=30000. What should I change it to? Why is streaming not retried ad infinitum until successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end it worked, after a dozen attempts. The difference was:

Raise streaming_socket_timeout_in_ms=600000 (10 min), to be longer than the longest imaginable GC pause (Maybe 0ms would have also worked.)

Before starting the bootstrap of the new node, do a rolling restart of the nodes in the same datacenter as the new node, so that their heap starts fresh, from a low value

Start the bootstrap at the end of the work day and leave it on overnight